# Google Maps - MySql - Get some Markers in the radius with a special lat and lng Coordinate

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, google-maps

Is it Possible to get only the latitude and longitude of coordinates in one special radius out of a database?

Comment: What exactly you want to do on Google Map or any other map?? Add markers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get google.maps.circle.getBounds() and google.maps.circle.fitBounds() to do this. These functions returns LatLngBounds.

```
var radius = new google.maps.Circle({
    center : myLatlng,
    radius : 500,
    fillOpacity : 0,
    strokeOpacity : 0,
    map : map
});
```

and then check for the latLng from your Database. For example:

```
radius.getBounds().contains( yourmarker.getPosition() ) ;
```

Refer the following link. It will be helpful..

http://www.paulmcilwaine.com/api/google-maps-detecting-markers-in-a-particular-boundary